# Install Contiki OS in Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, rf, atmega, atmel, contiki-os

I am just starting my IoT project. I want to implement a recent low-power wireless standards (6lowpan, RPL and CoAP) in my project. I found a  radio from Microchip (MRF24j40) that support IEEE 802.15.4 as a media transmitter. To coordinate the wireless system, I want to install the Contiki OS in my microcontroller. What I want to know is, whether is it possible to install Contiki OS in Atmel based MCUs (Atmega 16,etc.) and connecting it to MRF24j40 radio?

If it's not possible, is there any MCU suggestion that can I use to implement Contiki OS on it?

Comment: Did you [read this page](http://www.contiki-os.org/hardware.html)? Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, AVR should be supported.  See http://www.contiki-os.org/hardware.html .